# is there a way w/ git to see the base_tree of a tree?

Tags: git, github, github-api

Trying to figure out what happens under the hood of git operations.

Creating a tree is a part of making a commit.

According to the v3 api for git, creating a tree requires a base_tree (which can be empty). Api docs:

https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/

Is there a way (perhaps an option in git log) to see what the base_tree for a commit's tree is? Just trying to figure out for git cmd line operations exactly how they are creating trees and what the best practices are there.

Comment: Since you have not defined "base_tree" and there are multiple different definitions, you should probably define it first. I suspect you mean the one GitHub chooses indirectly (via its "base branch" notion, which is also a GitHub-specific notion, not part of Git) but that's just a *third* guess, in addition to the two in answers so far.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the base tree refers to the tree(s) of the commit's parent(s).

To find the parents of a commit `foo`:

```
git log -1 foo --pretty=%P
```

It may return:

1. nothing, when `foo` is a root commit;
2. one commit hash value, when `foo` is a common commit;
3. two values, when `foo` is a true merge commit;
4. more than two values, when `foo` is an octopus merge commit.

To find the tree of a commit `bar`:

```
git log -1 bar --pretty=%T
# or
git rev-parse bar^{tree}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the *tree* of the revision object, right? That can be seen very easily, actually:

```
git cat-file -p HEAD
```

Look at the tree id. That's the ID of the tree object that is at that revision. This also works:

```
git show --pretty=%T --quiet HEAD
```

You can use any revision other than HEAD, of course.

Comment: not quite, i'm trying to figure out what the base SHA of the tree is, ie, the base_tree sha was used to create the tree sha that is in %T